# Android studio github submission failed fatal: unable to access

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I am trying to share a project on github ; the repo is created but the when I try to commit I get this error

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/akash-pal/Popular_Movies_Stage_1.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: E:/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

**NOTE:** My Git is located in E:\Git

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What exactly is your question?

Comment: I am trying to share a project on android studio on github. However I get the above error message